# Rerender and useDeepCompareEffect don't seem to work together well

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

The answer to this question may very well be "don't do that", but I'd like to understand the behavior better.

I have a simple tree component that I want to rerender if the node list provided changes. The main use case is when the node list comes from a async call to the server. This is the relevant component file, minus the imports:

```
const TreeViewContainer = styled.div.attrs({
    'data-testid': 'tws-tree',
    role: 'tree',
})`
    padding: 0;
`;

type TreeViewAction = {
    type: 'refresh' | 'toggle';
    payload: ITreeNode | ITreeNode[];
};

const treeViewReducer = (state: ITreeNode[], action: TreeViewAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // Toggle open/closed on the parent (the node passed in) and visibility on that node's children.
        case 'toggle': {
            const incomingNode = action.payload as ITreeNode;
            const isOpen = !incomingNode.open || false;
            const newNode = { ...incomingNode, open: isOpen };
            const childNodes = state.filter((n) => n.parentId === incomingNode.nodeId).slice(0);
            childNodes.forEach((node) => (node.visible = isOpen));
            return state.map((node) => {
                if (node.nodeId === newNode.nodeId) {
                    return newNode;
                } else {
                    return childNodes.find((n) => n.nodeId === node.nodeId) || node;
                }
            });
        }
        case 'refresh': {
            return cloneDeep(action.payload) as ITreeNode[];
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export function TreeView(props: ITreeView) {
    const { nodes, onNodeSelected, renderFactory } = props;
    const [nodeList, dispatch] = useReducer(treeViewReducer, nodes);

    useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'refresh', payload: nodes });
    }, [nodes]);

    const handleNodeClick = (node: ITreeNode) => {
        if (node.hasChildren) {
            dispatch({ type: 'toggle', payload: node });
        } else {
            onNodeSelected(node);
        }
    };

    return (
        <TreeViewContainer>
            {nodeList
                ?.filter((n) => n.visible)
                .map((node) => {
                    return (
                        <TreeNode key={node.nodeId} {...node} onClick={handleNodeClick}>
                            {renderFactory(node)}
                        </TreeNode>
                    );
                })}
        </TreeViewContainer>
    );
}
```

This works fine in actual practice, and tests fine from the point of view of the component that renders the tree from a server-side call. This is probably where I should stop, but I have a lower-level test that broke once I refactored the tree to use `useDeepCompareEffect`:

```
test('rerenders the tree if the nodelist changes', () => {
    const nodeList: ITreeNode[] = [
        {
            nodeId: 'root',
            parentId: undefined,
            visible: true,
            open: true,
            hasChildren: true,
            depth: 1,
        },
    ];
    const { rerender } = render(<TreeView nodes={nodeList} onNodeSelected={jest.fn()} renderFactory={testRenderFactory} />);

    expect(screen.getAllByRole('treeitem').length).toBe(1);

    nodeList.push({
        nodeId: 'child',
        parentId: 'root',
        visible: true,
        depth: 2,
    });
    rerender(<TreeView nodes={nodeList} onNodeSelected={jest.fn()} renderFactory={testRenderFactory} />);
    
    expect(screen.getAllByRole('treeitem').length).toBe(2);
});
```

I'd like to know why this test is failing. Looking at the implementation of `useDeepCompareEffect`, it seems to me that it should see that change.

Debugging and console logging tell me that though the incoming nodelist changes, the effect isn't called (`dispatch({ type: 'refresh', payload: nodes });`). The assertion fails because only one treeitem is ever rendered in this test.

Answer (score 1):

I took my own advice -- "Don't do that."

Here's a better test:

```
test('rerenders the tree if the nodelist changes', () => {
    function RefreshHarness() {
        const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<ITreeNode[]>([
            {
                nodeId: 'root',
                parentId: undefined,
                visible: true,
                open: true,
                hasChildren: true,
                depth: 1,
            },
        ]);

        const handleClick = () => {
            setNodes([
                ...nodes,
                {
                    nodeId: 'child',
                    parentId: 'root',
                    visible: true,
                    depth: 2,
                },
            ]);
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={handleClick}>Test Me</Button>
                <TreeView nodes={nodes} onNodeSelected={jest.fn()} renderFactory={testRenderFactory} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    render(<RefreshHarness />);

    expect(screen.getAllByRole('treeitem')).toHaveLength(1);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /test me/i }));

    expect(screen.getAllByRole('treeitem')).toHaveLength(2);
});
```